# Attempting to conceptualize the correct data structure | Java

Tags: java, time, hash, heap, complexity-theory

**Input:**

A persons name (unique), and their score. 
I currently have it stored within a hashmap

```
HashMap<String, Integer> hmap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
hmap.put(name, score)
```

After the initial input, the score can be increased by passing in the name and the amount. This is a fairly easy thing to do as well.

```
 int removedVal = (Integer) hmap.remove(name); // removes the value 
 int newScore = removedVal + score; //adds new score to old
 hmap.put(name, newScore) //stores back into hashmap
```

**Problem**

I would like to allow the user to input a number and it will return the number of people who score is greater than such input.

The scores stored within the current hashmap are not unique, I would be unable to store them in their own reversed map because the duplicate scores would only be counted once.

```
TreeMap<Integer, String> tmap = 
new TreeMap<Integer, String>(); //unique values would be lost
```

**Question**

What is the most efficient way to find out which scores are above the desired input?

I am looking for the fastest way possible.

Edit: Would store in a hashmap for the names, and a heap for the values work?

Comment: "Most efficient" is a very vague term. What are your [actual requirements](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: Efficiency in terms of time complexity. Which data structure would be the fastest at tackling the task

Comment: You can use a multimap to track multiple names per count.

Comment: FYI, you can increment in one statement: `hmap.merge(name, 1, Integer::sum);`

Comment: Why limit yourself to Java objects? Why not a queryable in-memory database?

Comment: I believe a B-tree or SkipList indexed by score would be the most efficient

Comment: Names are not unique, you need to use something _truly_ unique for the key.

Answer (score 0):

What are possible values for scores? 
If the range is small, lets say 0 to 100 and values are integers then you can create another map `score -> count`. Insert/increment count for a score each time you add a name to your `hmap`. This adds small memory footprint and gives `O(1)` performance for fetching the count of scores greater than a certain score. 
And yes it is `O(1)` and not `O(n)` because processing time will not increase as you add more names.